# get values in url

Tags: php

I need to get values in the url as it is

ex:

http://www.example.com/index?url=**1+LY2ePh1pjX4tjZ4+GS393Y2pjd16Cbq63T3tbfzMzd16CarA==**

but vriable url give me value of  **"1 LY2ePh1pjX4tjZ4 GS393Y2pjd16Cbq63T3tbfzMzd16CarA=="**

Even though i have expected **"1+LY2ePh1pjX4tjZ4+GS393Y2pjd16Cbq63T3tbfzMzd16CarA=="**

any one can help me for this or know the reason

Comment: are you encoding your url or simply typing it that way?

Comment: i didn't do any encoding

Comment: it automatically convert + to " "  (space),that is the problem

Comment: A literal `+` character in a URI means "a space", that is why you have to encode it.

Answer (score 2):

You see, you need to encode certain characters if you need to send them in a URL. For further references, I suggest you should read this [Page](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp). It seems that the URL you are getting isn't being encoded properly. If the URL is coming from your site, then I would suggest you to encode it properly.

In PHP, there is a [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) called `urlencode`, which may help you with this task.

**A short explanation**

URLs can only be sent over internet using ASCII character set.If you want to send characters which is outside this set, you need to encode it.URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with `%` followed by two hexadecimal digits corresponding to the character values in the `ISO-8859-1 character-set`.

Comment: It’s rather UTF-8 that is used these days.

Answer (score 0):

The client sending the request apparently isn't URL encoding the value correctly. You can re-encode it after it's being decoded like this:

```
urlencode($_GET["url"])
```

Answer (score 0):

IT convert      **%2B**  to space

Comment: If you have a comment, make a comment. This is not the answer it claims to be.

Comment: Reputation 1 can't make comment I think. I don't think he deserves to be demoted for this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they can make comments on answers to their own questions.

Comment: @Rosdi & @David - scit can make comments in this thread. According to the FAQ: `you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep.` ( http://stackoverflow.com/faq )

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you sent is wrong, it should have been encoded like so..

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/index?url=', urlencode('1+LY2ePh1pjX4tjZ4+GS393Y2pjd16Cbq63T3tbfzMzd16CarA=='), '">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added encoding correctly now,It convert == correctly, but + sign encode to %2B correctly but in decode process it convert to space

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you’re having a Base-64 value there: You can use the [URL safe alphabet for Base-64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5) that uses `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/` respectively:

```
$base64 = "1+LY2ePh1pjX4tjZ4+GS393Y2pjd16Cbq63T3tbfzMzd16CarA==";
// plain Base-64 to URL safe Base-64
$base64_safe = strtr($base64, '+/', '-_');
// URL safe Base-64 to plain Base-64
$base64 = strtr($base64_safe, '-_', '+/');
```

And if you know the length of the data, you can also omit the `=` padding:

```
rtrim($base64, '=')
```